# Don't know how to access ParametricGeometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have tried to research how to access ParametricGeometry as I get this message every time I try to use it "THREE.ParametricGeometry has been moved to /examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js"

Any thoughts on how would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `import {ParametricGeometry} from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry.js'` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work. Maybe ill check out a different framework or something...

Comment: Sounds like you're getting ready to change a car, when you can't find a keyhole to start its engine, whereas you just need to press a button :)

Comment: ya... you're right
I ended up kind of fixing the issue by just going back a couple versions with <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r124/three.min.js"></script>

I guess it all works out in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, built with the docs:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import {ParametricGeometry} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometry";
import {ParametricGeometries} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/geometries/ParametricGeometries";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let contorls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new ParametricGeometry( ParametricGeometries.klein, 25, 25 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg") } );
const klein = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( klein );

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this seemed to do the job perfectly
Very Much appreciated.